# scrollLeft interferes scrollIntoView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

my website uses react-router-hash-link to scroll user to the section according to my navbar item. According to the source code from the library, they uses `scrollIntoView` to scroll user to the element's id.

Now i have this problem when user click on the navbar item; which should scroll to Section C, the browser stops at Section B where the `scrollLeft` function is used.

I came to the solution where the `scrollLeft` is interfering `scrollIntoView` by removing `scrollLeft` function, and it works normally!

Section B is a horizontal content which uses `scrollTop` to simulate a horizontal scroll.

Below is the picture for this situation. This bug only happens in Google Chrome desktop

[image]